# Is it possible to execute both onDestroy and fullSensor simultaneously

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

Is it possible to use these two methods in same app?

```
Use for :rotation with backhome(onDestroy)

  public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
           webview.destroy();
            finish();
           System.gc();
           //webview = null;
      }
```

And

```
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR); //in java file
or
    android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"//manifest
```

I want to rotate compatible and exit from app when click phone undo button.my app also use javascript.

Comment: What happens if you try it? Does it give an error? What is the error? No? Then what is not as expected?

Comment: OnDestry() is working properly while it working android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" is not working.